# How can I see the kernel stack function of a specific thread?

Tags: linux

I have a hung thread.
I am using gdb but it only shows me the system call the thread is stuck, but I would like to see the kernel function trace as well.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /proc/`PID`/task/`TID`/stack
```